# How to hide / close the error message automatically while using <p:message>?

Tags: jsf, user-interface, primefaces

I have this specification that when error message is displayed (while using `<p:message>`) due to validation message or some thing else it should close after sometime automatically.

How can i do that?

I am using primefaces

please give me a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that. Try to combine functions `delay()` and `hide()`. Here are links:
[hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you got the following code in your page

```
<h:form id="form1">  
    <p:messages id="messages"
```

and you have a `<p:commandButton`

Than you could do something like (You might need to replace `$` with `jQuery`)

```
<p:commandButton onsuccess="setTimeout ( '$(\'#form1\\\\:messages\').hide()', 100);"...
```

Note that I've used `\'` and `\\\\` to escape the `'` and `\\`

you can specify timeout delay in milliseconds , I used `100` milliseconds