# How to hide error messages dynamically when user clears input data

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using PrimeFaces. The Input is validated when the user presses the "save" button, but I need to clear the error messages dynamically when the user clears the input field.

```
<div class="item">
    <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="#{msgs['customerForm.firstName']}"/>
    <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{customerBean.customer.firstName}"
            requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.mandatory']}"
            required="true"
            validatorMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.wrongFormat']}">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="m_zeroField"/>
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*)?$"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message id="m_firstName" for="firstName" display="text"/>
    <p:message id="m_zeroField" for="firstName" display="text" rendered="#{customerBean.customer.firstName.isEmpty()}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the expected and actual behavior?

Comment: You can use `<p:ajax update="m_zeroField, m_firstName" />`

Comment: actual behavior is all err messages appears dinamical whrn user enters data in field, I expect to show them only when user press button save and only dinamical hide them if user clearing input field

Comment: Did you try to clear the content like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271737/how-to-hide-pmessages-after-it-displayed-the-messages at the right time?